# How to conditionally call a function for each row in R?

Tags: r, function, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to call a function that provides a value for specific data elements in a table.

A data table (gameData) might be:

```
            Date TeamA TeamB TeamAScore TeamBScore
    1 2016-03-06   NYC   HOU         67         76
    2 2016-02-14   BOS   SEA        NaN        NaN
    3 2016-01-30   LAS   DAL         63         74
```

I would like to populate the TeamAScore with the return of a function if it is NaN. I tried a function like the following:

```
gameData$TeamAScore <- ifelse(
  is.nan(gameData$TeamAScore),
  getTeamAScore(gameData$TeamA,gameData$TeamB,gameDate=gameData$Date),
  gameData$TeamAScore
)
```

When I run this, I get a an error like the following:

> Error in Ops.factor(teamdata$Team, TeamA) : 
>     level sets of factors are different

It seems to be sending all of the TeamA's with the function call instead of only the value for that row.

Comment: How does the function getTeamAScore() look like?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the TeamA and TeamB columns do not have the data you think they have. Factors are tricky in R...

Let's create two factors here to see what is happening:

```
> TeamA <- factor(c("NYC", "BOS", "LAS", "SEA"))
> TeamB <- factor(c("HOU", "LAS", "NYC", "SEA"))
> TeamA
[1] NYC BOS LAS SEA
Levels: BOS LAS NYC SEA
```

OK, so TeamA has four slots: NYC, BOS, LAS and SEA. So we can compare this to TeamB to see whether any slot in the two vectors is the same. Right? Wrong:

```
> TeamA == TeamB
Error in Ops.factor(TeamA, TeamB) : level sets of factors are different
```

That is the same error you are receiving! That happens because what is really stored in this vectors is a number representing each "factor level".

```
> str(TeamA)
 Factor w/ 4 levels "BOS","LAS","NYC",..: 3 1 2 4
> levels(TeamA)
 [1] "BOS" "LAS" "NYC" "SEA"
> levels(TeamB)
 [1] "HOU" "LAS" "NYC" "SEA"
```

So, 1 represents BOS in the TeamA vector, but it represents HOU in the TeamB vector. Of course they can't be compared!

How to avoid using factors when they are getting in your way? Use the argument `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` when you create the data.frame (either using `data.frame(x, y, z, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` or read.csv("filename.csv", etc, etc, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`.

Comment: That seemed to clear up the first error, but it seems like I am getting a similar error for the date. in The getTeamAScore function, I subset a data set with the date like so: playerData <- playerData[ which(playerData$Date < as.Date(gameDate,"%Y-%m-%d")), ]   ; It gives me a 1: In `<.default`(playerData$Date, as.Date(gameDate, "%Y-%m-%d")) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length  // warning. Any thoughts on why this is?

Comment: Also, by using a print(TeamA), print(TeamB), and print(gameDate) inside my function, I see that it is sending all rows to the function and not just one row at a time. How can I send just one row to the function for execution?

Comment: You can use a "for" loop, and index each row, something like `for (i in 1:4) getScore(TeamA[i],TeamB[i])`, this will pass each row to the function. Is this what you're looking for?